# PHP login full name not detected

Tags: php, authentication

I am running a script locally.

I've created two different usernames with their own full name.
**Example:**

- first username **User1** with Full Name named **User One**, and
- second username named **User2** with Full Name named **User Two**.

So, when I log in using username **User1**, the system detect the true full name named **User One** but when I log in using username **User2** why the system still detect also as **User One**.

It's like the system cannot read other's full name from database.

My code as below:

As usual, it has a session:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
```

This is my code for declaration that connect to database:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_kiki, $kiki);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT name FROM `ahli`";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $kiki) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
```

And here is my code for printing the full name after logging in.

```html
Welcome, <?php echo $row_Recordset1['name']; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not selecting the right name in your query. You need to add:

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT name FROM `ahli` where `username`= ".$_SESSION['username'];
```

This, assuming you have stored the users username with sessions.

What's happening now is that you fetch all the users, and only display once the name. Because User One is the first in the returned array, it will always display User One.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be:

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT name FROM `ahli` where `username`= 'User2'";
```